# Views not showing in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my first project with Angular. I'm still in the process of figuring out how to do things with Angular, so I'd like to apologize if my questions sound stupid.

---

### My Questions

- Why are my views not showing up when i navigate to `index`?
- How can I fix this?

---

### Overview

So, my `index` file shows the views I have used in the `ui.router` library. `form.html` contains my template header and footer. Within that file, I then have another...

```
<div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
```

... that should inject all my nested views.
However, when I go to `index`, I'm just getting a blank page and no errors!

---

### Source code

**app.js**

```
angular.module('MyFirstAngularApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router']);
```

**config.js**

```
angular.module('MyFirstAngularApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])

// configuring our routes
// =============================================================================
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('form', {
            url: '/form',
            templateUrl: 'views/form.html',
            controller: 'formController'
        })

        // nested states
        // each of these sections will have their own view
        // url will be nested (/form/signup)
        .state('form.signup', {
            url: '/signup',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-signup.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/select
        .state('form.select', {
            url: '/select',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-select.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/type
        .state('form.type', {
            url: '/type',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-type.html'
        });

    // catch all route
    // send users to the form page
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/signup');
});
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/darkly/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/override.css">

    <!-- JS -->
    <!-- load angular, nganimate, and ui-router -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>


</head>

<!-- apply our angular app -->
<body ng-app="MyFirstAngularApp">

<div class="container">
    <!-- views will be injected here -->

    <div ui-view></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**form.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

    <div id="form-container">

        <div class="page-header text-center">
            <h1>Mock up Maker</h1>

            <!-- the links to our nested states using relative paths -->
            <!-- add the active class if the state matches our ui-sref -->
            <div id="status-buttons" class="text-center">
                <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".signup"><span>1</span> Sign Up</a>
                <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".select"><span>2</span> Select</a>
                <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".type"><span>3</span> Type</a>
                 <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".end"><span>4</span> End</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- use ng-submit to catch the form submission and use our Angular function -->
        <form name="myForm" id="signup-form" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" ng-submit="processForm()">

            <!-- our nested state views will be injected here -->
            <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
        </form>

    </div>

    <!-- show our formData as it is being typed -->
    <pre class="col-sm-12 ng-binding">
    {{ formData }}
</pre>

</div>
```

**File structure**

[image]

I don't see why its not working. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Getting any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors, im just doing some research atm if ive used ui.views correctly

Comment: You are defining your angular-module twice:
app.js :

`angular.module('MyFirstAngularApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router']);`
config.js :

`angular.module('MyFirstAngularApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])`

Comment: Thanks, so I should only call it in app.js ?

Comment: You should define it once, and reference to it latter without an array (`angular.module('MyFirstAngularApp').controller(.......`)

Comment: plus 1 for a bit of education, thanks you

Comment: so like `angular.module('MyFirstAngularApp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {`

Comment: @OmriLuzon perfect, works thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet

```
angular.module("moduleName", [])
```

defines a new module with the required dependencies in the array. If you want to further define components of this module, you need to define them using

```
angular.module("moduleName")
  .controller(...)
  .directive(...)
  .config(...)
  .run(...);
```

The latter is a getter syntax of angular module and doesn't define the module again.

Your current code defines the module `MyFirstAngularApp` two times. That should be the root of your problem.

You probably want:

```
angular.module('MyFirstAngularApp').config( ...
```

in your **config.js**

This avoids duplicating the module, instead it gets the instance already created in `app.js` and adds configuration on it. The same approach should be used in your controllers and other code.

Comment: perfect, works fine +1 ill accept your answer in 5 mins (@OmriLuzon got it forst want to see if he provides a write up)

Comment: @Beep It's fine, you can accept his answer, I wasn't sure if it would solve your problem because you said there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in your Views template folder. In the file structure directory you are having Views Folder whereas you are using lowercase views name in routing.

Comment: thanks, ive renames the folder to views but still not working